# Publish Azure Application with MSBuild

Tags: azure, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

Visual Studio 2013 has a publish wizard for Cloud Service projects that packages and deploys a cloud service based on settings persisted in a .azurePubxml file.

I'm setting up automation of this process on a CI server, and want to leverage this functionality within MSBuild, but I'm unsure if it's even possible.

I have found a lot of articles that talk about shelling out to a PowerShell script and using a custom MSBuild target file to do the deploy, but that seems like a duplication of information that I'd rather not delve into.

Given that I have the Azure subscription credentials installed on the build machine, VS 2013, and Azure SDK 2.2, can I invoke the same mechanism that VS 2013 uses in the publish wizard to package and deploy my cloud service?

Currently, using MSBuild with the publish target, I can package the service into a .cspkg file, but I cannot figure out how to trigger to package/deploy based on a profile (.azurePubxml file) that defines the VS build config, and all of the Azure settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as you pointed out, the default targets will only give you a package. From there, Visual Studio is publishing things using their own infrastructure. Publishing the build from a CI server is considered something external to actual build process and rather something that is part of the deployment process.

If your CI technology has support for PowerShell then it's as easy as automating the Windows Azure PowerShell cmdlets to do your bidding. [There's a nicely detailed article on how you might do this with Team Builds in TFS here on MSDN](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/continuous-delivery/).

Comment: That makes sense, it's just a bummer that developers cannot leverage the infrastructure outside of a dev machine. The pub xml file have everything I need in them...I guess I'll have to parse them in the script.

Comment: You can completely automate the whole procedure using powershell script in fact from the point of Package Generation to Publish - http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/jumpstart-31-create-and-deploy-new-azure-cloud-service-using-package-cspkg-generated-by-azure-powershell/. Kust call this script from MSBuild.

Comment: I ended up following the article posted by @drew-marsh below. It's  little out-of-date, but I did get it to work. If you copy and paste the powerscript from the article, watch out for funky characters. This tripped me up for some time until I opened the script in PowerShell ISE and the syntax highlighting pointed out the problems.